# ASP.net: dynamically load web user control

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net web page with place holder control and Menu control when user select an item from the menu. It will dynamically load the control based on menu item's value.

I got the control loaded but if i click on the a link button or anything on the web user control (.ascx) The web user control (.ascx) will disappear. I do not know what is causing this. Can someone take a look at my code and see what i'm missing?

```
Protected Sub Menu1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Select Case Me.Menu1.SelectedValue
        Case "CustMasterMain"
            Dim ccCustMasterMaint As UserControl = CType(Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/Franchise/CustMasterMaintControl.ascx"), UserControl)
            Me.phHolder1.Controls.Add(ccCustMasterMaint)
        Case "AcctRecInq"
            Dim ccAcctRecInq As UserControl = CType(Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/Franchise/custAccountsReceivableInquiry.ascx"), UserControl)
            Me.phHolder1.Controls.Add(ccAcctRecInq)
    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember that each time you do a postback you are working with a brand new instance of your page class.  If you added the control to the controls collection of a previous instance of your page class, you *need to add it again for every postback that follows.*

Additionally, if you want ViewState to be restored for the control then it needs to be added to the page *before* the Load event.  That means adding the control during Init or PreInit.

Answer (score 2):

Joel is correct that you need to add the control on every postback so you need a way to track what controls are stored on the page.

The [Dynamic Controls Placeholder](http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx) is an excellent control for helping manage dynamic controls on your page across postbacks. I'd recommend you check it out as I've used it on a number of projects and it's made life a lot easier for me.