# Server session still alive, but data being lost

Tags: c#, .net, iis, postback

Ok, so after a bit of fiddling I've finally identified an issue I've been having.

I have a website that on initialization initializes different objects and fills them with data.  This includes datasets and a custom controller on different pages.  This problem appears to affect my site on all pages inconsistently.

I'll go with the error I have the most detail on.  I have a comment page where a person can dynamically create comment boxes and a drop down list filled with data.  At initial load only one of the comment boxes are created.  When you click a button, a post back occurs and another button will be loaded into a list containing all the comment boxes and the additionally comment box will be displayed.

Now this works fine, ispostback = true and the count of the list is incremented by one.  This is all hosted on a windows 2012 server under iis.  The website is set for sessions through a sql server and the limit is 20 minutes for the session.  The site also uses cookies that last for a month to contain some metadata.  Now, if I wait for 5 minutes or so (I remain inactive at the web page), and hit the button again, what sometimes happens is that it will take awhile to load, the ispostback will be true, it will go into the addbuttonclick method and start to add the next comment box to the list, it will load the previous data for the comment box to the new one, and this is where it will error.  The commentcontrol list somehow get's cleared out and the count when I receive the error is 1.  Meaning that the server... cleared the comment list randomly.

Similar problems are also plaguing other pages I have though that's more datasets getting cleared.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Initialization on page load

```
  if (!IsPostBack)
        {                    
                DataSet BudgetCodes = new DataSet();
                BudgetCodes = WFlowWS.GetBudgetCodes();
                commentControl.Clear();
                //intialize comment control            
                this.CommentControl1.Ds = BudgetCodes;
                this.CommentControl1.FillBudgetCode(this.CommentControl1.Ds);
                if (commentControl.Count == 0)
                {
                    commentControl.Add(this.CommentControl1);
                }
            }
```

The btnaddadditionalComment click

```
    protected void btnAddAdditionalCom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            commentControl.Add(LoadControl("~/WorkflowCommentControl.ascx") as WorkflowCommentControl);
        }
        catch (Exception exl)
        {
            Response.Write(exl.ToString() + "line 1");
            Response.End();
        }
        try
        {
            Response.Write("ISPOSTBACK " + IsPostBack.ToString() + "   COMMENT CONTROL COUNT : " + commentControl.Count().ToString() + "     ");
            commentControl[commentControl.Count() - 1].Ds = commentControl[(commentControl.Count() - 2)].Ds;
        }
        catch (Exception exl)
        {
            Response.Write(exl.ToString() + "line 2");
            Response.End();
        }
        try
        {
            commentControl[commentControl.Count() - 1].FillBudgetCode(commentControl[commentControl.Count() - 2].Ds);
        }
        catch (Exception exl)
        {
            Response.Write(exl.ToString() + "line 3");
            Response.End();
        }
        try
        {
            this.PanelComment.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        }
        catch (Exception exl)
        {
            Response.Write(exl.ToString() + "line 4");
            Response.End();
        }
        try
        {
            this.PanelComment.Controls.Add(commentControl[commentControl.Count() - 1]);
        }
        catch (Exception exl)
        {
            Response.Write(exl.ToString() + "line 5");
            Response.End();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exl)
    {
        Response.Write(exl.ToString() + "line 6");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

cookie life is one month, session timeout is set for 30 minutes.

Session state settings are sql server,

connection string is below (slightly modified)

Server=tcp:90210.database.windows.net,1433;Database=USState;User ID=Pirates;Password=Boats;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;

timeout 30 seconds, connection retry interval 0, enable custom database is checked.

Cookie settings
Mode: Use Cookies
Name: ASP.NET_SessionId
Time-out : 20

use hosting identity for impersonation is checked

Basic IIS setting for application pool are

.Net Framework v4.0.30319
Managed pipeline mode: integrated
Start application pool immediately is checkmarked

Code at the very end of page load which loads each comment control

```
for (int x = 1; x < commentControl.Count; x++)
        {
            this.PanelComment.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
            this.PanelComment.Controls.Add(commentControl[x]);
        }
```

Comment: Show us the code behind.

Comment: code is worth a million words. Code and error only.

Comment: edited to include the code of the comment control initialization and what happens when btn add additional comment is clicked

Comment: Is anything being caught in the global error handler (global.asax / Application_Error)? I had a similar problem and it turned out to be a a thrown exception invalidating the session, but only for some browsers.

Comment: The error, when actually thrown (inconsistently) is caught in the btnAdditionalCom_Click,  specifically line 2.

Comment: By any chance are you writing anything on hard disk somewhere in your web app? In it's directory?

Comment: no, not that i know of at least

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your session timeout variable may just be too low.  It's also possible your app pool is recycling due to memory usage or some other issue; could you tell us your IIS settings on that app pool for recycling?

Comment: @IvanS your app pool recyling seems to be suspect then. Can you check those settings and see if they seem low? If you're on IIS7+, you can add an event to the logs so you could see: http://blogs.iis.net/ganekar/archive/2008/12/12/iis-7-0-application-pool-recycles-log-a-event-in-windows-event-log.aspx

Comment: recycling setting for the app pool have only regular time intervals in minutes checked with a time of 1740.

Comment: Also set app pool recycling to be an event,  does not appear to be getting recorded by the event viewer

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically adding UserControls to a web page, you need to do it every page load. It forgets (or more correctly, never knows) about the previous state of the page.

More info here - [ASP.net: dynamically load web user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440854/asp-net-dynamically-load-web-user-control)